# Why we define the adjoint operator

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose in vector space $A: X\rightarrow Y$ is a linear map, the adjoint operator $A^{'}: Y^{'}\rightarrow X^{'}$ is defined as:
$f(Ax)=(A^{'}f)(x)$.

As I can understand, the adjoint operator just give a map to represent $fA$, so why does we define the adjoint operator,and how can we link each other?

Comment: There is a theorem that matrix representing the adjoint operator $A'$ is the transpose matrix of the matrix representing $A$. I think the purpose that mathematicians define the adjoint as you wrote is to link the adjoint and transpose.

Comment: Honestly, there's a lot to be said here, and it's hard to easily say exactly what that is. One application: suppose you want to solve the least squares problem for the overdetermined system $Ax=b$. One can show (more or less using the Pythagorean theorem) that you then want $Ax-b$ to be orthogonal to $Ay$ for every vector $y$, that is, $(Ax-b,Ay)=0$ for every $y$. The adjoint in an inner product space satisfies $(Aq,r)=(q,A'r)$ for every $q,r$, so you have $(A'(Ax-b),y)=0$ for every $y$. This forces $A'(Ax-b)=0$, which is called the *normal equations* for the least squares problem.

Comment: (Note that I already sneakily used the Riesz representation theorem to identify $X$ with $X'$ and $Y$ with $Y'$.)